# Did a jpeg2000 file corrupt my install?

Tags: nautilus, jpeg

While running UBUNTU 14.04 I navigated to this web page
http://www.fnordware.com/j2k/jp2samples.html
and downloaded their linked example jpeg2000 format graphics file 
http://www.fnordware.com/j2k/relax.jp2
to my desktop.

When I clicked on the file to see if the default image viewer would open it, 
my system went crazy.
After about a minute I decided to press the system reset.
My system rebooted, but the desktop background disappears after a second and
the desktop is totally black.
UBUNTU reported a serious system error.
Whenever I click on the launcher file system icon, Nautilus will bring up the
window for a second, then the Nautilus window goes away.
Thankfully the launcher still works and I am able to access the Terminal and installed programs.
Viewing the system processes using the top command shows that the Nautilus process dies without error.
Sometimes, usually within a few minutes of booting the system reports a serious error and it stops responding.
Is it possible that clicking on that .jp2 corrupted my system because of something that I've done in system configuration, or is this a nasty bug in UBUNTU?  Or was it just bad luck such as a cosmic ray hitting my circuitry.

I went to the Software Center and downloaded an alternative file manager (Thunar), so I'll be able to backup my files to an external drive, but my system is no longer stable.

I'm hoping that someone with deep skills can determine if clicking on that file really damaged my system (much like a virus), and how to fix it so I won't have to restore from a backup or re-install a new version.

Of course it would be best if this error can not be reproduced by anyone.   If so, I'll live with the restore or reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more playing around with the Thunar file manager and was finally able to trash the downloaded file off my desktop.

It wasn't just clicking on the file that caused problems, apparently  **the mere presence of that jpeg2000 file on my UBUNTU desktop causes the wild instability!**

As soon as I deleted the file, the desktop reappeared and Nautilus resumed it's correct functioning.

My guess is that in addition to being bad to click on, the file's presence triggers a very bad desktop icon generation bug preventing the desktop.
However because my file system defaults to browsing the "Home" folder which did not contain the suspect file, and it was not attempting to display the .jp2 icon, I am a bit unsure why that file manager window display would also disappear, therefore my analysis might be incorrect.

This seems to be nasty bug which might cause a novice user to reinstall the OS because of the desktop not working.